# How do you customize tabs as a regular user in Salesforce Lightning?

Tags: lightning, custom-object, tab

What is the Lightning equivalent of `Customize My Tabs` in Classic?

Answer (score 0):

You can finally personalize your Navigation in Lightning Experience as of Spring 18 release.

See the release notes here: **[Supercharge Your Productivity with Personalized Navigation in Lightning Experience](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lightning_personalized_nav.htm)**